# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its depend

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure function which reads from an Azure Service Bus Queue and write to Azure blob storage as a part of the message processing.

The Blob writing is done using the `azure-storage-net-data-movement` library.

The logic for processing the message and writing to the blob sits in different projects that the Azure Function project.

While writing to the blog, I’m constantly getting

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Tried changing all projects to .Net 4.6/.1/.2, installing the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.5 updates but no luck.

Getting the same error running locally as well as in the cloud.
When I read from the queue using a console application the same solution works as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Function SDK is using `7.2.1` version of Storage library, so you get version conflict. May I ask why you use `azure-storage-net-data-movement`?

Comment: @Mikhail the azure-storage-net-data-movement library significantly improves performance when uploading and moving huge files to the blob storage. I strongly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Mikhail for pointing me to the right direction.

Function SDK is using 7.2.1 version of Storage library, whereas the data movement library depends on >= 8.4.0.
So the fix was to simply add the package `WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.5.0.0` to the Azure function project.