# SSIS - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 Connection Issue

Tags: azure, ssis

I am currently working on an SSIS project to push some file to Azure Datalake Gen 2. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the connection part. Indeed, testing the connection to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 generates the following error:

> Test connection failed: Could not load file or assembly
> "Micorosoft.azure.Strorage.Common, Version = 11.1.3.0, Culture =
> neutral .....

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

After some research, I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655773/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-version-8-5-0-0) that recommends applying the TLS 1.2 protocol by modifying the registers. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected.

Has anyone experienced this problem and how did you get around it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I ran into an issue with the Azure Feature pack where the error was similar (could not find a DLL) but the root cause was a TLS restriction in Azure https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2022/01/ssis-azure-feature-pack-and-flexible.html  Either set the registry key or dial down the requirement on the Azure side

Comment: Thank you for your feedbak. changing the register does not solve the problem for me. Also, for some reason I will not be able to switch to TLS 1.0. Where can I see more details about the origin of the error?